# how do you set up dynamic where conditions with sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have to create a dynamic sequelize query, it can have 1 to 3 conditions, the first one is a like query, the second two are exact matches. The user can select any combination. I can't seem to format the where condition on this for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

This worked, after playing around with it.

I used typescript so adjust if you are not.

```
let whereClause = {};

if (searchCriteria.documentName) {
  whereClause['documentName'] = {
    $like: '%' + searchCriteria.documentName + '%'
  };
}

if (searchCriteria.language) {
  whereClause['targetLanguage'] = searchCriteria.language;
}

if (searchCriteria.department) {
  whereClause['departmentName'] = searchCriteria.department;
}

let documents = await this._model.DocumentTranslation.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: this._model.Document
  }],
  order: [
    ['createdAt', 'ASC']
  ],
  where: whereClause
});
```